# Swift: Extra Argument in call when setting value

Tags: ios, swift, set

```
fileprivate func setInitialValues() {
    radius = (frame.size.width/2.0) * 0.8 //We always apply a 20% padding, stopping glows from being clipped
    backgroundColor = .clear
    set(colors: .white, .cyan)
}
```

I am getting the error 'Extra argument in call' on the set(colors: .white, .cyan) line of code.

Comment: This code is part of the KDCircularProgress indicator cocoapod

Comment: It's `set(colors:`, not `set(colours:`. Maybe you also have a typo in the code?

Comment: well spotted, the typo is not in the code though!

Comment: Then I don't see why you get this error. They're [doing the same](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress/blob/master/KDCircularProgress/KDCircularProgress.swift#L227). :/ Just in case, did you try just without the argument label? Maybe the method signature changed. Also try to trigger Xcode's autocomplete.

Comment: Error has only appeared since I migrated my project to swift 3.

Comment: Ok then it's probably a Swift 3 method renaming issue. Try using Xcode's autocomplete: start typing only `set(` then wait for completion (or hit ESC).

Comment: You know more about KDCircularProgress, but most signatures that take more than one argument call for an array. Shouldn't there esquire brakes around the colors?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/kaandedeoglu/KDCircularProgress/issues/49) helps.

Comment: Xcodes autocomplete has changed the code from set(colors: .white, .cyan) to set(.white, .cyan) and this seems to have ressolved the issue. Thanks guys!

Comment: @dfd, Swift allows using [`variadic parameters`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html), for caller it looks like code above: just coma separated values, but inside function it's treated as an array.

Comment: @RyanHampton I see that they had a `setColors(...)` method with variadic input and no external label. I guess this has been automatically imported as `set(...)` in Swift 3, probably shadowing (or replacing) the `set(colors:)` one.